# Directing Selenium Tests to Various Platforms on Grid doesn't work?

Tags: selenium, grid

Selenium 2.38.0, Grid2, Java 1.7, TestNG Framework, Firefox 27.0, Chrome 33.0, Windows 7, Windows 8

1. Summary - I have a Selenium Grid2 setup on 5 VMshares in a lab, the nodes are as follows:

Hub - Win7
Node 1 - Win7/Firefox
Node 2 - Win7/Chrome
Node 3 - Win8/Firefox
Node 4 - Win8/Chrome

1. Issue, I'm passing in the platform as an XML Parameter with TestNG to set the platformName and platform capabilities when the Selenium Driver starts up so the hub will direct it to the correct node. This doesn't seem to work, the tests always seem to start on the first node which is Win7/Firefox only. Here's the driver code where I setup it up for Firefox as an example:

   ```
    public void setDriver(String browser,String environment,String platform) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {      
    switch (browser) {
    case "firefox":
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    ffProfile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile(Constants.FF_PROFILE_PATH);

    caps =  DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,ffProfile); // RemoteWebDriver must use DesiredCapabilities, WebDriver can use same or Options...

    // this directs what remote grid node to run on...
    if ( environment.equalsIgnoreCase("remote") ) {
       switch(platform) {
       case "Window 7":
          caps.setCapability("platform","WINDOWS");
          caps.setCapability("platformName","WIN7-firefox");
          break;
       case "Window 8":
          caps.setCapability("platform","WIN8");
          caps.setCapability("platformName","WIN8-firefox");
          break;
       default:
          break;
       }

       this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Constants.REMOTE_HUB_URL),caps);
    }

    else
       this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(caps);

    break;
   ```
2. If I change the XML parameter  to "Windows 8", sometimes it starts on the Windows 7 node, ocassionally it starts on the Windows 8 node if the other ones are busy. Anyone know why this would not work, I have the nodes configured via a JSON config file as follows:

Node 1:

```
{
   "capabilities":
   [
      {
         "platformName": "WIN7-firefox",
         "browserName": "firefox",
         "browser-version": "",
         "maxInstances": 1,
         "platform": "WINDOWS",
         "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
         "acceptSslCerts": true,
         "javascriptEnabled": true,
         "takesScreenshot": true
      }
   ],
```

Node 2:

```
"capabilities":
   [
      {
         "platformName": "WIN8-firefox",
         "browserName": "firefox",
         "browser-version": "",
         "maxInstances": 1,
         "platform": "WIN8",
         "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
         "acceptSslCerts": true,
         "javascriptEnabled": true,
         "takesScreenshot": true
      }
   ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because that your win7 node uses the platform "WINDOWS", which means that it can accept any windows execution request including windows 8.

Though it doesn't look that good, you can use "VISTA" instead of "WINDOWS" to separate the two platform group. I wonder why they don't add "WIN7" option or self defined condition.

Apparently, the platformName does not work here.

Comment: I would like execute in Linux Platform ?

May I know what i have to be specify ?